# Rust: What does the `@` (at sign) operator do?

Tags: rust

I saw the following line in my code, and I am not sure what it does as I haven't encountered the `@` operator before.

```
if let e@Err(_) = changed {
    ...
}
```

Can this line be written without the `@` operator, what would that look like?

Comment: This is essentially equivalent to `if changed.is_err() { let e = changed; ... }`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a [way to *bind the matched value of a pattern to a variable*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns)(using the syntax: `variable @ subpattern`).

Example:

```
let x = 2;

match x {
    e @ 1 ..= 5 => println!("got a range element {}", e),
    _ => println!("anything"),
}
```

Comment: So (A) `if let Err(e) = changed` is different from (B) `if let e@Err(_) = changed`?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge. `@` binds the *matched value* which will be `Result`(assuming `changed ` is of `Result`) type. So the type of `e` in the second case(`B`) is type of `changed`

Answer (score 3):

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#-bindings and https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns, it is used for simultaneously matching to the pattern to the right of the `@` while also binding the value to the identifier to the left of the `@`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, Yes, it would look like

```
if let Err(_) = &changed {
    // continue to use `changed` like you would use `e`
}
```

Note that in order to continue to use `changed` inside the body, you need to match for the reference `&changed`. Otherwise it will be moved and discarded (unless it happens to be `Copy`).

Comment: I don't think the last sentence is accurate. `if let Err(_) = changed` will nevver move `changed`, since there is no target on the left-hand side it could be moved to. ([Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/))

Comment: Also note that the idiomatic way to write this is `if changed.is_err()`.

Comment: An exact equivalent (matching movedness and drop behavior) would be `if changed.is_err() { let e = changed; ...}`